# Is the following set is compact

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

Consider the set of all $n \times n$ matrices with determinant equal to one in the space of $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$.

My idea is compact because determinant function is continous ant it is bijective from the given set to $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R$ is Hausdorff, so image of compact set  is compact.

Answer (score 3):

the determinant is not bijective! This set not bounded, because of the matrices $$\operatorname{diag}(R,R^{-1},1,1,\dots,1)$$ (let $R\rightarrow \infty$)

Comment: What abut compactnes

Comment: in every $\mathbb R^m$ compact is the same as closed and bounded.

Comment: the special case $n=1$ requires attention...

Answer (score 2):

In $\mathbb R^m$, with the usual metric topology, a set is compact iff it is closed and bounded. The set you describe is closed (since it is the inverse image of a closed set under a continuous function) but it fails to be bounded if $n>1$ (and the case $n=1$ is trivial, do you see why?). Try to find matrices with arbitrarily large entries, but still having determinant $1$.